# Как подключить библиотеку на этапе компоновки?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

Работаю над нужным мне проектом. В С++ не сильно разбираюсь, но нужно воспользоваться этим проектом. Там есть такой фрагмент исходного кода:

```
#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only              \
    high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")     \
    rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")
using namespace mscorlib;
```

Но при комприляции (так понимаю, точнее на этапе компоновки) вылетает ошибка `E1696 cannot open source file "my_path\Debug\mscorlib.tlh"`. Хотя `my_path\Debug\mscorlib.tlh` уже существует. Почему тогда вылетает эта ошибка?

Возможно, это дубликат этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384157/importing-a-lib-file-using-visual-studio/19384667, но в моём случае подключается .tlh, а не .lib. Или это не имеет значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E1696 - это никак не ошибка компоновки (ошибки компоновки имеют вид "LNK...", а компиляции - "C..."). Это ошибка IntelliSence, которая в VS2017 показывается даже после успешной компиляции. Чтобы избавиться от нее, нужно в окне ошибок выбрать режим "только сборка". (В VS2012 она исчезает после первой успешной компиляции без необходимости что-то настраивать.) Если у вас проект действительно не собирается, проблема не в tlh, а в чем то другом.

Comment: А кстати формат .tlh это прекомпилед хеадер? или символы? или кусок IntelliSence?

Comment: @NewView tlh-файл это обычный заголовочный файл, генерируемый средством импорта tlb, который содержит объявления констант и интерфейсов для данной библиотеки

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так и думал

Answer (score 2):

Если .tlh-файл еще не был создан на момент открытия проекта в VS2017, то IntelliSence продолжает отображать эту ошибку (E1996) даже после удачной генерации .tlh-файла.

Поэтому, после того, как .tlh-файл создался при сборке, приходится помогать IntelliSence — в окне "Обозреватель решений" включить-выключить отображение всех файлов проекта (или просто перезапустить VS2017).

Если лишь отключить показ ошибок IntelliSence в окне "Список ошибок", как советовал @MSDN.WhiteKnight, то все-равно до перезапуска отображается красное подчеркивание в коде 
(хотя этим отключением тоже пользуюсь, потому что после "E1696" у меня начинают сыпаться "E0102", которые пока еще [не исправлены и в новой VS2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/569429/not-possible-to-suppress-intellisense-warning-in-g.html)).